# how to save image from a drawView to a specified folder

Tags: java, android, drawing, draw, save-image

i want to know if i can save the image drawn at a drawView to a specified folder. For example i want to save the image to myLectureImage folder. And also i want to retrieve the image on the app.

thanks for your help.

```
package com.example.ddsk;

import java.util.UUID;
import com.example.ddsk.myLectureView;
import com.example.ddsk.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Drawing extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button btnback;
private myLectureView drawView;
private ImageButton currPaint, drawBtn, eraseBtn, newBtn, saveBtn;
private float smallBrush, mediumBrush, largeBrush;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lctr);


    drawView = (myLectureView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);
    LinearLayout paintLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
    currPaint = (ImageButton)paintLayout.getChildAt(0);
    currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));

    smallBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
    mediumBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
    largeBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.large_size);

    drawBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.draw_btn);
    drawBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);

    eraseBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.erase_btn);
    eraseBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    newBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.new_btn);
    newBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    saveBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void paintClicked(View view){
    //use chosen color

    drawView.setErase(false);
    drawView.setBrushSize(drawView.getLastBrushSize());

    if(view!=currPaint){
        //update color
            ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton)view;
            String color = view.getTag().toString();

            drawView.setColor(color);

            imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
            currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint));
            currPaint=(ImageButton)view;
        }

    }

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
//respond to clicks
    if(view.getId()==R.id.draw_btn){
        //draw button clicked
        final Dialog brushDialog = new Dialog(this);
        brushDialog.setTitle("Brush size:");

        brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.brush_chooser);

        ImageButton smallBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush);
        smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(smallBrush);
                drawView.setErase(false);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        ImageButton mediumBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush);
        mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                drawView.setErase(false);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        ImageButton largeBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush);
        largeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setBrushSize(largeBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(largeBrush);
                drawView.setErase(false);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        brushDialog.show();
    }

    else if(view.getId()==R.id.erase_btn){
        //switch to erase - choose size
        final Dialog brushDialog = new Dialog(this);
        brushDialog.setTitle("Eraser size:");
        brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.brush_chooser);

        ImageButton smallBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush);
        smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton mediumBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush);
        mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton largeBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush);
        largeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(largeBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        brushDialog.show();
    }

    else if(view.getId()==R.id.new_btn){
        //new button
        AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        newDialog.setTitle("New drawing");
        newDialog.setMessage("Start new (you will lose the current one)?");
        newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                drawView.startNew();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        newDialog.show();
    }

    else if(view.getId()==R.id.save_btn){
        //save drawing
        AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        saveDialog.setTitle("Save drawing");
        saveDialog.setMessage("Save drawing to device Gallery?");
        saveDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                //save drawing
                String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(),
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png", "drawing");

                if(imgSaved!=null){
                    Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    savedToast.show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Oops! Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    unsavedToast.show();
                }
            }
        });
        saveDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        saveDialog.show();

        drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        drawView.destroyDrawingCache();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.sfo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.sof.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get our application's root view.
        final View view = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

        // read documentation.
        view.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // save the whole app view
                saveView(view);
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveView(final View view) {
        String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String targetDirPath = storagePath + "/myLectureImage/";

        File targetDir = new File(targetDirPath);
        if (!targetDir.exists()) {
            if (false == targetDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Could not create dir: " + targetDirPath);
                return;
            }
        }

        String filePath = targetDirPath + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png";
        File file = new File(filePath);
        Log.d(TAG, "File path: " + filePath);

        try {
            file.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream ostream = null;
            ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();

            // NOTE: in production code, you should not be doing this from 
            // UI thread - as compress method will take some time for high 
            // quality images
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();

            // Update the new image information in media store so that it is visible in gallery app
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[] { filePath }, null,
                    new OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            // careful! you can not touch views or show toast from here. This is an async task callback.
                            Log.d(TAG, "Saved: " + path);
                        }
                    });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error saving file: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sfo.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sof"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sfo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Note the permissions needed in manifest.

Comment: Which onClick() method are you referring to?

Comment: This one:  R.id.save_btn

Comment: we get error when pressing save button. it say java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please copy-paste the complete stack trace for that exception here.

Comment: i get the java.lang.NullPointerException at bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);

Comment: i've edited my answer. bitmap shall be initialized with the bitmap object from drawing cache. if you are still getting this object null, check to see whether you have enabled drawing cache.

Comment: can you add a reference, source or example for us to see? thank you

Comment: check the answer. i've added code of a complete working app to do this. this app will save the content of the whole app view to file and you can see it in gallery.